# Angular2 mouseover or mouseleave causes app's bindings to refresh

Tags: angular, binding, refresh, mouseover, mouseleave

So I am using angular2 RC4, when I bind these events, all elements bindings on the page is refreshed, This is annoying b/c I have video content that restarts from the beginning. I didnt see this issue anywhere else, so I could be doing something wrong.

```js
//FrontPage
import template from './FrontPage.html';

@Component({
  selector: 'front-page',
  template,
  directives: [VideosDisplay_New, VideosDisplay_Watch, VideosDisplay_Complete, NavBar, StickyPos, SideBarRight, Carousel, ModalDirective]
})
export class FrontPage {
  
    public clButton : CLButton;
    
    @ViewChild('episodeModal') episodeModal: ModalDirective;
    public clickedEpisodeModal : OuNeRe;
    @ViewChild('seriesModal') seriesModal: ModalDirective;
    public clickedSeriesModal : ThCoMe_OuSe;
    
    constructor (){
       
        this.clButton = CLButton;      
    }

    public navBool : boolean = false;
    public sidebarTop : number = 55;
    public navStyle : string = 'relative';
    
    
    public navExpand() : void{
        this.sidebarTop = 55;
        this.navBool = false;
        this.navStyle = 'relative';
    };

    public navCollapse() : void {
        this.sidebarTop = 10;
        this.navBool = true;       
        this.navStyle = 'absolute';
    };
}

//Carousel
import template from './Carousel.html';

@Component({
  selector: 'carousel',
  template,
  directives: [CollapseDirective, TOOLTIP_DIRECTIVES, CElement, CElementVideos]
})
export class Carousel implements OnInit{
    
    private currentIndex = 0;
    private skip : number = 0;
    private ouFe : OuFe;
    private results : StdSequence ;
    public ces : any[] = [];
    
    public constructor (ouFe : OuFe) {
        this.ouFe = ouFe;
    }
    
    ngOnInit () {
        
        this.results = this.query(0);   
        
        this.results.observeChanges({
            addedBefore :function(id, fields, before){
                this.results = this.ouFe.fFind({},{limit:6});
            }.bind(this)    
        });
    }
      
    query (skip : number) : StdSequence {
        return this.ouFe.fFind({},{'skip':skip, limit:6});    
    }
}

//CElementVideos
import template from './CElementVideos.html';

@Component({
  selector: 'celement-videos',
  template,
  directives: [CollapseDirective, TOOLTIP_DIRECTIVES]
})

export class CElementVideos {
    
    @Input() src : string = "";
    @Input() caption : string = "NA";
    
    public constructor (){
    }
}
```

```html
<!-- front page html view -->

<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row fixed-nav" 
   (mouseover)="navExpand();" 
  (mouseleave)="navCollapse();"
  [ngStyle]="{'position': navStyle}">
  <nav-bar  class="col-md-12"></nav-bar>
 </div>
    <!-- video content -->
   <div class="row content-bottom-space">
  <carousel></carousel>
 </div>
</div>


<!-- video container view, Carousel.html -->
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row absolute-parent"> 
  <div *ngFor="let ce of results; let i = index">
   <celement-videos *ngIf="ce.fDocumentTypes()[1] == 'Videos'" [src]="ce.fGetVideo(0)" [caption]="ce.fTitle()" class="col-sm-2"></celement-videos>
  </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- video component view, CElementVideos.html-->
<div>
 <video [autoplay]="true" [muted]="true" controls>
  <source [src]="src" type="video/webm">
  <source [src]="src" type="video/mp4">
  <source [src]="src" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
 </video>

</div>
```

So what is up with the mouse events?

Comment: Where are the `mouseover`  or `mouseleave` events?

Comment: They are in "front page html view". However, I didnt solve this problem instead I found a work around. Dont think what I posted could have helped anyone to help me solve it. In the end it had to do with "change detection" mechanism in angular2. I believe I was incorrectly implementing iterable causing my collection to seem different/new every time. This caused change detect to invalidate and refresh at every mouse event. To work around for now, I extended arrays.